# Spring Data with Postgres issue: How to pass timezone parameter into native query?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a native query:

```
@Query( value = "select to_char(o.earliest_delivery_time at time zone 'UTC', 'Mon YYYY') as month, " +
        " count(o.id) as orderQuantity, " +
        " sum(lp.net_qty) as gallonQuantity " +
        " from orders o " +
        " left join lifts l on o.id = l.order_id " +
        " left join liftproducts lp on l.id = lp.lift_id " +
        " where earliest_delivery_time>= :startReportDate " +
        " AND o.status in :statuses" +
        " AND (o.bill_to_id IN  (:userCompany)" +
        "        OR o.carrier_id in  (:userCompany) OR o.retailer_id in  (:userCompany)" +
        "        OR o.wholesaler_id in  (:userCompany) OR o.requestor_id in (:userCompany)) " +
        " group by to_char(o.earliest_delivery_time at time zone 'UTC', 'Mon YYYY')", nativeQuery = true)
List<OrdersByTimeDashboardDto> getOrdersByTime(@Param("startReportDate") Instant startReportDate,
                                               @Param("userCompany") Long userCompany,
                                               @Param("statuses") Collection<String> statuses,
                                              );
```

And it works fine, but now I want to pass timezone as parameter, so:

```
@Query( value = "select to_char(o.earliest_delivery_time at time zone :timezone, 'Mon YYYY') as month, " +
            " count(o.id) as orderQuantity, " +
            " sum(lp.net_qty) as gallonQuantity " +
            " from orders o " +
            " left join lifts l on o.id = l.order_id " +
            " left join liftproducts lp on l.id = lp.lift_id " +
            " where earliest_delivery_time>= :startReportDate " +
            " AND o.status in :statuses" +
            " AND (o.bill_to_id IN  (:userCompany)" +
            "        OR o.carrier_id in  (:userCompany) OR o.retailer_id in  (:userCompany)" +
            "        OR o.wholesaler_id in  (:userCompany) OR o.requestor_id in (:userCompany)) " +
            " group by to_char(o.earliest_delivery_time at time zone :timezone, 'Mon YYYY')", nativeQuery = true)
    List<OrdersByTimeDashboardDto> getOrdersByTime(@Param("startReportDate") Instant startReportDate,
                                                   @Param("userCompany") Long userCompany,
                                                   @Param("statuses") Collection<String> statuses,
                                                   @Param("timezone") String timezone
                                                  );
```

for example timezone can be: `String timezone = "UTC";`
And after this changes, I received an error:

> ERROR: column "o.earliest_delivery_time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I tried a lot of solutions, but nothing works for me.

Comment: That's really odd. Can you show how the query looks like after you pass all parameters?

Comment: Your contention "returned result is incorrect", while probably true is  absolutely useless. Please post test data (as text - no images), the expected results, and the actual results. Perhaps also see [mre].

Comment: Try keeping only o.earliest_delivery_time in your group by clause, not the entire month calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and the following change solved it.

Try to use:

```
group by month
```

Instead of:

```
group by to_char(o.earliest_delivery_time at time zone :timezone, 'Mon YYYY')
```